# Convert CGSize to CGFloat and use that to size a RoundRectButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, strlen, string-length, sizewithfont

I'm trying to find the physical pixel size of a string of text. I then want to use this size to set the length of a roundRectButton. The method I'm using to get the length however returns a CGSize. How do I convert that to a CGFloat? Alternatively perhaps someone can suggest a totally different way to accomplish this.

This is the code I have currently:

```
// Note: tagAsString is a string of Tag names (Example "tag1, tag2, tag3")
// Note: Code to set this is not relevant to the question.

// get length of tagsAsString.
CGSize tagStringLength = [tagsAsString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0] forWidth:100.0 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

// size button to fit length of string
// Note: spotTags is a roundRectButton
cell.spotTags.frame = CGRectMake(96, 33, tagStringLength, 25);

// set the title of the roundRectButton to the tag string
[cell.spotTags setTitle:tagsAsString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As you can see above I'm using the CGRectMake method which takes 4 arguments as CGFloat. I am however passing in a CGSize which is causing a run-time error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CGSize` is a structure:

```
struct CGSize {
   CGFloat width;
   CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```

Just use `tagStringLength.width` to get the number you care about.

And I'm pretty sure you should be getting a compile-time error, not a run-time error.

Comment: That's a beautiful thing, and yes you are right its a compile-time error. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`CGSize` is a struct of two elements: `CGFloat` width and `CGFloat` height.

Example code:

```
CGSize size;
CGFLoat width = size.width;
CGFLoat height = size.height;
```